# XPATH: Finding rows that contain multiple texts

Tags: xpath

Im not sure why but the below query

```
.//*[@id='training_modules_list_table']/thead/tr[th[text()='ID']and th[text()='NAME']and th[text()='STATUS']and th[text()='VERSION']and th[text()='PACKAGE']and th[text()='REFERENCE']]
```

does not find anything in the html below.

```
<table class="table  sortable stripe tablesaw-stack" data-tablesaw-mode="stack" id="training_modules_list_table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th data-sort="int"><a href="/test1/admin/training?direction=asc&amp;sort=id">ID</a></th>
              <th data-sort="string"><a href="/test1/admin/training?direction=asc&amp;sort=name">Name</a></th>
              <th data-sort="string"><a href="/test1/admin/training?direction=asc&amp;sort=status">Status</a></th>
              <th data-sort="string"><a href="/test1/admin/training?direction=asc&amp;sort=version">Version</a></th>
              <th data-sort="string"><a href="/test1/admin/training?direction=asc&amp;sort=package">Package</a></th>
              <th>Assigned Study</th>
              <th data-sort="string"><a href="/test1/admin/training?direction=asc&amp;sort=reference">Reference</a></th>
              <th data-sort="string"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <tr>
```

Comment: Try to replace predicate `[text()="value"]` with `[.="value"]` or `[a/text()="value"]`

Answer (score 0):

While your question has less information that what actually you want to achieve but after seen your xpath it looks you are trying to write a xpath which return you all a tag element.

Try below xpath :-

```
//table[@id='training_modules_list_table']//tr/th/a
```

It will return you all element in `a` tag

Hope it will help you :)